# Create event and share variables

Tags: multithreading, delphi, events, variables, delphi-2007

I am using Delphi 2007 and threads.

My problem (sorry, i'll try to explain better):

1) I created a file "utilities.pas" where i have the function i use more.
2) I created a new program, in this program i have one thread
3) in the execute method of the thread i call one function in my file "utilities.pas".
   this function connects to an ftp using clever components (tclftp). This components logs the server responce in a dedicated event. What i would like to do is to save the log in a stringlist and then send the stringlist back to the calling thread.

This is part of the file "utilities.pas":

```
// I created TEventHandlers because it's the only way to assign the event runtime
// without having a class
type
 TEventHandlers = class
  procedure clFtp1SendCommand(Sender: TObject; const AText: string);
 end;

var EvHandler: TEventHandlers; 

// this is the porcedure called from the thread. i want to send the stringlist
// back to it containing the ftp log
procedure Test(VAR slMain: tStringlist);
var cFTP: TclFtp;
begin
 cFTP := TclFtp.Create(nil);

 cFTP.Server := 'XXX';
 cFTP.UserName := 'XXX';
 cFTP.Password := 'XXX';
 cFTP.OnSendCommand := EvHandler.clFtp1SendCommand;

 // i connect to the ftp
 cFTP.Open;

 FreeAndNil(cFTP);
end;

procedure TEventHandlers.clFtp1SendCommand(Sender: TObject; const AText: string);
begin
 // here the component (cftp) sends me back the answer from the server.
 // i am logging it

 // HERE IT'S THE PROBLEM:
 // I can't reach slMain from here.....

 slmain.add(Atext);
end;
```

this is the calling thread:

```
procedure TCalcThread.Execute;
var slMain: tstringlist;
begin
  inherited;

  slmain := tstringlist.create(nil);

  Test(slmain);

  if slMain.count > 0 then
    slMain.savetofile('c:\a.txt');

  // i won't free the list box now, but in the thread terminated.
end;
```

this is the main program:

```
procedure TfMain.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
Var ExThread: TCalcThread;
begin
  ExThread := (Sender as TCalcThread);

  if ExThread.slMain.Count > 0 then
    ExThread.slMain.SaveToFile('LOG\Errori.log');

 freeandnil(slMain);
end;
```

Please can anybody help me in solving this? I really don't know what to do.
I hope now it more clear.

p.s. thanks for all the answer..

Comment: Typo: slMail should be: slMain

Comment: I assume that you need to do something with slMain after you call cFTP.Open?  If so, you should put in a comment. Otherwise, as written, slMain is irrelevant.

Comment: Does procedure "Test" get run within a thread?  If so, you should make that clear.

Comment: What determines the parameter list for clFtp1SendCommand?  If it's something you wrote  yourself, just pass slMain as another parameter.  If not, what exactly is Sender going to be?  If that's an object that you can attach slMain to, your problem is solved.

Comment: We need more details.  What is the list to contain and what do you want to do with the list contents?  Like @ChrisThornton says, you could pass the thread instance as the sender and retrieve the list that way.

Comment: ok i added all the details, sorry for that. clFtp1SendCommand is one of the default events of the component, so I cannot change it unfortunately...

Comment: my goal is to connect to an ftp, get the logs from the server and save the log to file. I have to save the log at the end of the thread because I need it to stay all together in case of multiple threads. the problem is that i can get the server-answer just in that build-in event..

Answer (score 0):

I think one (BAD) approach would be to create a pool of components in the main thread or at design time, and assign one to each thread. i.e. 5 instances of cFTP, 5 stringlists, 5 threads.

Update: Martin James points out why this is a terrible idea, and I agree. So don't do this. Post stays as a deterrent.

Comment: Breaks encapsualtion - the forms/main thread does not need access to the FTP component/s.  There is a lot less chaos if each thread creates its own components and lists - why should the main thread do it?  Also, dumping components onto forms that are then used by secondary threads obliges the user to terminate the secondary threads before the form is closed on shutdown to prevent AV/216/217 exceptions.  There are far too many 'how do I shut down my thread cleanly' posts on here already - if it can be avoided, avoid it!

Comment: Agreed. Bad idea. Editing to reflect what not to do.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to have your thread object have its own instance of the stringlist and its own cFTP.  If you need to have one "master thread" that everything writes to (perhaps for a summary of what each thread accomplished), use this class:
TThreadStringList by Tilo Eckert
http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=2167

Answer (score 0):

Intercept the event within the thread class, and fire an own typed event from within that handler. Synchronize this call! And try to prevent the global variable. All this as follows:

```
type
  TFtpSendCommandEvent = procedure(Mail: TStrings; const AText: String) of object;

  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FclFtp: TclFtp;
    FslMail: TStrings;
    FOnFtpSendCommand: TFtpSendCommandEvent;
    FText: String;
    procedure clFtpSendCommand(Sender: TObject; const AText: String);
    procedure DoFtpSendCommand;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    // You could add this property as parameter to the constructor to prevent the
    // need to assign it separately
    property OnFtpSendCommand: TFtpSendCommandEvent read FOnFtpSendCommand
      write FOnFtpSendCommand;
  end;

// If you dont want to make this a property or private field of the thread class:
var
  EvHandler: TFtpSendCommandEvent;

{ TMyThread }

procedure TMyThread.clFtpSendCommand(Sender: TObject; const AText: string);
begin
  // Store the AText parameter temporarily in a private field: Synchronize only 
  // takes a parameterless method
  FText := AText;
  Synchronize(DoFtpSendCommand);
end;

procedure TMyThread.DoFtpSendCommand;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnFtpSendCommand) then
    FOnFtpSendCommand(FslMail, FText);
  // Or, if you really like to use that global variable:
  if Assigned(EvHandler) then
    EvHandler(FslMail, FText);
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  ...
  FclFtp := TclFtp.Create(nil);
  FslMail := TStringList.Create(nil);
  try
    FclFtp.Server := 'XXX';
    FclFtp.UserName := 'XXX';
    FclFtp.Password := 'XXX';
    FclFtp.OnSendCommand := clFtpSendCommand;
    FclFtp.Open;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(FclFtp);
    FreeAndNil(FslMail);
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the help. sorry if i did not explain very well before but my function (test) it's not in the tread directly. It's called from a thread and it's part of a file called "utilities.pas". so i don't think i can use this. I also thought about creating a big thread class inside "utilities.pas" containing all the procedures I use more often but then i stopped because i don't know how to call all of them from the main program since I would have to call the function "RunThread" and not the procedures directly...